# Deleting class pointer

Tags: c++, pointers, visual-studio-2013

I have class Connection:

```
class Connection{
    public: Connection(string usr, string pwd);
            ~Connection();
    private:
        Engine *        pEngine;
        AdmCallbacks * pAdmCallbacks;
        Callbacks *      pCallbacks;
        char *           fake[11];
        int              iFlags;
        int              iCode;
};

~Connection()
{
        delete pEngine;
        delete pCallbacks;
        delete pAdmCallbacks;
}
```

in main.cpp i do this code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include "Connection.h"
using namespace std;
int main()
{
  Connection *connection = new Connection("test","test");
  if (logedin)
      //do something
  else delete connection;
  if (connection != NULL)
    cout << "WTF" << endl;
  return 0;  
}
```

Output:

```
WTF
```

Why? I dont understand why the memory is not dispose.. Help me please, Thx!

Comment: Why do you think `delete`ing it will then set the pointer to `NULL`? (Hint: it won't - you are just responsible for not reusing it)

Comment: @BoBTFish then how i can checked that the pointer is null after deleting? I need to set it to NULL?

Comment: Why do you need it to be `NULL`? It's `delete`d. There should be no need for you to go near it again. But yes, in some cases you might want to reuse a pointer, in which case you would manually set it to `NULL` to know that you need to allocate something there again before using it.

Comment: @BoBTFish Yes, i need to use it again, looak at the code, i add some lines. So if loginfailes (in else) i need to add "connection = NULL" after deleting ?

Comment: To be clear, you don't need to set the pointer to NULL before reusing it. Furthermore, consider not using new at all. `Connection *connection = new Connection("test","test");` could be `Connection connection ("test","test");`

Comment: @NeilKirk its really good, but i have another question: What will happen with class connection, if i set it to NULL without deleting? the memory is disposed?

Comment: You will leak memory. In modern C++ you should avoid new as much as possible and use smart pointers if necessary. This makes it harder to leak memory.

Comment: @NeilKirk hm, i just test it, and i dont have any leaks

Comment: How do you know that?

Comment: @NeilKirk D: okay, i understand you. Thanks!